# New predictions when model contains a poly term

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, prediction, predict

I am trying to predict `y` for a new vector of data `x_new` by hand. By "by hand" I mean not using the `predict` function (my actual model is an `mcmc` object which `predict` doesn't accept). This is fine with a simple model like this:

```
lm1 <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length + Sepal.Width + Sepal.Length, data=iris)
x_new <- c(1, 1.4, 3.2, 5.2)
y <- x_new %*% lm1$coef
```

But I'm not sure how to proceed when my model looks like:

```
lm2 <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length + Sepal.Width + poly(Sepal.Length,3), data=iris)
```

How exactly do I use the parameters from the `poly()` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `poly(., raw=TRUE)` so it uses raw rather than orthogonal polynomials. Compare, now they yield the same coefficients:

```
lm2 <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length + Sepal.Width + Sepal.Length +
            I(Sepal.Length^2) + I(Sepal.Length^3), data=iris)
lm3 <- lm(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length +  poly(Sepal.Length, 3, raw=TRUE), 
          data=iris)

> coef(lm2)
      (Intercept)      Petal.Length       Sepal.Width      Sepal.Length I(Sepal.Length^2) I(Sepal.Length^3) 
      10.22126962        0.50889848        0.22999328       -5.81536464        0.98349473       -0.05626378 
> coef(lm3)
                       (Intercept)                       Petal.Length                        Sepal.Width poly(Sepal.Length, 3, raw = TRUE)1 
                       10.22126962                         0.50889848                         0.22999328                        -5.81536464 
poly(Sepal.Length, 3, raw = TRUE)2 poly(Sepal.Length, 3, raw = TRUE)3 
                        0.98349473                        -0.05626378
```